# React @flow avoid duplicate type for this

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype, create-react-app

I'm using flow along with `create-react-app`. And sometimes it easy to use `this.someFlag` to setup some flags in `constructor(props)`, but `@flow` yell on me.
Temporary solution is using `any` type for `this`. Like so: `(this: any).timerID = null;`
I don't really like it, because I have to use it everywhere and the code becomes whole mess. It's really not comfortable.
Can I define `this: any` for current component somehow so I won't repeat it everytime ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this quite easily:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  myThing: number;

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.myThing = 1;
  }

  render() {
    return <div>my component</div>
  }
}
```

you just need to define a type on the class.